# Can i use Xpath for list of <td> elements to get list of names instead of javascript?

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, selenium, xpath

Can I use `XPath` for a list of `<td>` elements to get a list of names instead of javascript?

For example,

In [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/chart/top) if we say:

```
 "$x('//tbody//tr[1]//td[2]/a/text()')"
```

using chrome browser, we get first movie title.

If I really want 250 movie titles, should I go some javascript and iterate over all elements ., or is there any solution to get all movie titles with only `XPATH` itself?

Comment: You want to do only with XPATH? What if find the parent and iterate the child?

Comment: In what environment are you trying to do this? Your question is tagged with "selenium" but your question doesn't mention selenium anywhere.

Comment: Do you using selenium web driver?

Comment: I'm trying to find these in developers tools of chrome browser , and Yes, i tried with selenium webdriver it worked , but i want to know how do with only XPATH

Answer (score 2):

You can't use a single xpath to find all `tds`. You have to find the parent element and then iterate the children.

Something like this:

```
List<WebElement> rows = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("table[class='chart']")).findElement(By.tagName("tbody")).findElements(By.tagName("tr")); //list of all rows
for(WebElement row: rows)
   //do your operation here
```

Comment: Are you saying that XPath is not capable of expressing such a query, or simply that Selenium cannot do it?

Comment: Selenium can do this with iterating over <td>, but i'm interested in finding with only Xpath in developer tools of any browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `[1]` from your `tr`, you should be able to get all the matching items:

```java
List<WebElement> links = 
         driver.findElements(By.xpath("/table[@class='chart']/tbody/tr/td[2]/a"));
for (WebElement link : links) {
    System.out.println(link.getText());
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, never tried this. Guess selenium should be able to find all matching elements.

Comment: I Understand that selenium will do job, but i need to understand about XPATH, does it have capability to get entire movie list in above example??

Answer (score 0):

If you run something like tagsoup on your HTML it will turn it into well formed XML and once it is well formed XML you can do whatever you want with whatever version of Xpath you like.